# Display no post when metavalue is 0

Tags: meta-query

There is a page displaying the 3 most popular posts, using the post views on the query. When there are no post views, I don't want to display any posts.

How can I display no post when `post_views_count` is 0? I think I'm missing something in my meta query. What's wrong?

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'list',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
    'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
    'value' => 50,
        'compare' => '>'
        )
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an updated example that appears to do what you want. See the docs for [meta queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments) for details.

```
$query_args = [
    'post_type'      => 'list',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'meta_query'     => [
        [
            'key'      => 'post_views_count',
            'value'    => 50,
            'compare'  => '>',
            'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
        ],
    ],
];

$post_views_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
```